# How to use an external dll file in a managed visual c++ project generated through firebreath

Tags: firebreath

I have to use some functions of an external dll file in my firebreath project. This project is managed c++ project. I want to know how to refer or include the external file in my project.I am not getting the Add Reference option in my visual studio 2010 (because this is a managed c++ project). Please tell me a way to do this..

Comment: If this is plain unmanaged Dll, do this by general native C++ rules: all .lib file to the linker dependencies list, and call Dll functions from the code. Don't use Add Reference function - it is only for .NET or COM libraries.

Comment: @AlexFarber..But I have only dll file not a .lib file. Moreover, I don't know whether it is plain unmanaged dll or something else..

Comment: @AlexFarber..Moreover,the dll file is actually C# dll and I have to refer or use its functions in a managed c++ project generated through firebreath.

Comment: In VS2012 C++/CLI project this function is here: Solution Explorer - Right-click on the project item - References - Add New Reference. Hopefully, in VS2010 this is the same. Why do you call it "managed C++" and not C++/CLI, maybe this is very old VS2003 language version?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you know the names of the functions you want to call within the DLL, the mechanism you have to use is the following:

```
// these are examples of functions --> change return values and params as needed
typedef CHAR (WINAPI *DLL_FUNC1) (USHORT, USHORT);
typedef CHAR (WINAPI *DLL_FUNC2) (USHORT, UCHAR*, UCHAR*, USHORT, UCHAR*, USHORT*, UCHAR*);
typedef CHAR (WINAPI *DLL_FUNC3) (USHORT);

// load library
HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary( L"\\path\\to\\your.dll" );

// check if dll was loaded 
if (hDLL == NULL) {
    // error 
    return;
}

// assign functions
DLL_FUNC1 func1 = (DLL_FUNC1) GetProcAddress( hDLL, "name_of_func1" );
DLL_FUNC2 func2 = (DLL_FUNC2) GetProcAddress( hDLL, "name_of_func2" );
DLL_FUNC3 func3 = (DLL_FUNC3) GetProcAddress( hDLL, "name_of_func3" );

// use functions --> here func1 as an example
if( func1( 1, 2 ) != OK ) { // or whatever return value
    // error
    FreeLibrary( hDLL ); 
    return;
}

// --> go on working with the DLL functions

// do not forget to call at the end
FreeLibrary( hDLL );
```